# Windows 7 Can't Access Ubuntu Computer on Network

Tags: 12.04, samba

My network currently has 3 Windows 7 computers on it and one Ubuntu 12.04. When clicking on "Network" in Windows Explorer on any of the three Windows computers, you can see all the other computers, including the Ubuntu one, and access all three Windows computers. However, when I click on the Ubuntu one, it says "Windows cannot access \UBUNTU. You do not have permission to access \UBUNTU. Contact your network administrator..."

My ultimate goal is for anyone on the network, no password required, to be able to access the drives I'm trying to share, and read/write to them (security risk, I know, but I'll chance it). But at this point, I'll settle for just being able to access it, and I have no clue why I can't.

I know I should post the contents of my samba.conf and my fstab, since I'm trying to share NTFS drives, but I can't even figure out how to post them on here. It's really not a good day for me, computer-wise.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To post the files just edit your question, paste the text into and mark it as code with <$> or Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with a two step solution.

1. I went to my public folder "Properties" tab in Ubuntu and clicked "Sharing Options." I then clicked "Share this folder" and "Guest access."
2. I then went to the "Ubuntu Software Center" and installed "Samba" (I like GUI better than terminal.) Then I ran Samba to setup the same Samba user name and password that I have on the Windows computer.  Finally, I set up the guest account the same as the windows username.